# Buttons and textboxes not showing text

Tags: microsoft-band

I'm trying to create a tile with 3 pages, each page contain a textbox and a button. Here is my code

```
[self.client.personalizationManager
     themeWithCompletionHandler:^(MSBTheme *theme, NSError *error){
         if (error){
             // handle error
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         }
         NSLog(@"Creating tile...");
         NSString *tileName = @"SnapBand";

         // Create Tile Icon
         MSBIcon *tileIcon = [MSBIcon iconWithUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Band46x46.png"] error:nil];

         // Create small Icon
         MSBIcon *smallIcon = [MSBIcon iconWithUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Band24x24.png"] error:nil];

         // Create a Tile
         NSUUID *tileID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"6120f0c7-fec4-44b0-99fa-04c7ca6cf869"];
         MSBTile *tile = [MSBTile tileWithId:tileID name:tileName tileIcon:tileIcon smallIcon:smallIcon error:nil];

         // Create a Picture Text Block
         MSBPageTextBlock *pictureTextBlock = [self createMSBandTextBlockWithParameters:10 WithTheme:theme];

         // Create a Picture Snap Button
         MSBPageTextButton *pictureButton = [self createMSBandActioButtonWithParameters:11 WithTheme:theme];

         // Create a Movie Text Block
         MSBPageTextBlock *movieTextBlock = [self createMSBandTextBlockWithParameters:20 WithTheme:theme];

         // Create a Movie Snap Button
         MSBPageTextButton *movieButton = [self createMSBandActioButtonWithParameters:21 WithTheme:theme];

         // Create a Brust Text Block
         MSBPageTextBlock *brustTextBlock = [self createMSBandTextBlockWithParameters:30 WithTheme:theme];

         // Create a Brust Snap Button
         MSBPageTextButton *brustButton = [self createMSBandActioButtonWithParameters:31 WithTheme:theme];

         MSBPageFlowPanel *pictureFlowPanel = [[MSBPageFlowPanel alloc] initWithRect:[MSBPageRect rectWithX:0 y:0 width:245 height:105]];
         MSBPageFlowPanel *movieFlowPanel = [[MSBPageFlowPanel alloc] initWithRect:[MSBPageRect rectWithX:245 y:0 width:245 height:105]];
         MSBPageFlowPanel *brustFlowPanel = [[MSBPageFlowPanel alloc] initWithRect:[MSBPageRect rectWithX:490 y:0 width:245 height:105]];

         [pictureFlowPanel addElements:@[pictureTextBlock, pictureButton]];
         [movieFlowPanel addElements:@[movieTextBlock, movieButton]];
         [brustFlowPanel addElements:@[brustTextBlock, brustButton]];

         MSBPageScrollFlowPanel *panel = [[MSBPageScrollFlowPanel alloc] initWithRect:[MSBPageRect rectWithX:0 y:0 width:245 height:105]];
         panel.horizontalAlignment = MSBPageHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
         panel.verticalAlignment = MSBPageVerticalAlignmentTop;
         panel.orientation = MSBPageFlowPanelOrientationHorizontal;

         [panel addElements:@[pictureFlowPanel, movieFlowPanel, brustButton]];
         MSBPageLayout *layout = [[MSBPageLayout alloc] init];
         layout.root = panel;

         [tile.pageLayouts addObject:layout];

         [self.client.tileManager addTile:tile completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
             if (!error || error.code == MSBErrorTypeTileAlreadyExist)
             {
                 NSLog(@"Creating page...");
                 NSUUID *pageID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"a234e9ba-1c09-46c3-b3b3-12bb1c9cf90f"];
                 NSArray *pageValues = @[[MSBPageTextButtonData pageTextButtonDataWithElementId:11 text:@"Snap!" error:nil],
                                         [MSBPageTextBlockData pageTextBlockDataWithElementId:10 text:@"Picture" error:nil]];
                 MSBPageData *pageDataPicture = [MSBPageData pageDataWithId:pageID layoutIndex:0 value:pageValues];

                 NSUUID *pageIDMovie = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"1535d78b-9784-4892-a94c-030df63de453"];
                 NSArray *pageValuesMovie = @[[MSBPageTextButtonData pageTextButtonDataWithElementId:21 text:@"Snap!" error:nil],
                                         [MSBPageTextBlockData pageTextBlockDataWithElementId:20 text:@"Movie" error:nil]];
                 MSBPageData *pageDataMovie = [MSBPageData pageDataWithId:pageIDMovie layoutIndex:1 value:pageValuesMovie];

                 NSUUID *pageIDBrust = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"1fd74789-3936-4324-a1fc-3e1d66d6e189"];
                 NSArray *pageValuesBrust = @[[MSBPageTextButtonData pageTextButtonDataWithElementId:31 text:@"Snap!" error:nil],
                                              [MSBPageTextBlockData pageTextBlockDataWithElementId:30 text:@"Brust" error:nil]];
                 MSBPageData *pageDataBrust = [MSBPageData pageDataWithId:pageIDBrust layoutIndex:2 value:pageValuesBrust];


                 [self.client.tileManager setPages:@[pageDataPicture, pageDataMovie, pageDataBrust] tileId:tile.tileId completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                     if (!error)
                     {
                         NSLog(@"Completed band tile creation");
                         [self.snapPictureButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GreenStatus"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                         [self sendHapticFeedback];
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                     }
                 }];
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
             }
         }];

     }];
```

I created a constructor method to generate textboxes and buttons, the methods are:

```
 -(MSBPageTextBlock *) createMSBandTextBlockWithParameters:(int)textBoxID WithTheme:(MSBTheme *) theme{
    MSBPageTextBlock *textBlock = [[MSBPageTextBlock alloc] initWithRect:[MSBPageRect rectWithX:0 y:0 width:200 height:40] font:MSBPageTextBlockFontSmall];
    textBlock.elementId = textBoxID;
    textBlock.baselineAlignment = MSBPageTextBlockBaselineAlignmentRelative;
    textBlock.horizontalAlignment = MSBPageHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    textBlock.autoWidth = YES;
    textBlock.color = theme.baseColor;
    textBlock.margins = [MSBPageMargins marginsWithLeft:15 top:0 right:0 bottom:0];

    return textBlock;
}
```

and

```
-(MSBPageTextButton *) createMSBandActioButtonWithParameters:(int)textBoxID WithTheme:(MSBTheme *) theme{
    MSBPageTextButton *actionButton = [[MSBPageTextButton alloc] initWithRect:[MSBPageRect rectWithX:0 y:0 width:200 height:40]];
    actionButton.elementId = textBoxID;
    actionButton.horizontalAlignment = MSBPageHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    actionButton.pressedColor = theme.baseColor;
    actionButton.margins = [MSBPageMargins marginsWithLeft:15 top:0 right:0 bottom:0];

    return actionButton;
}
```

The buttons and the textboxes doesn't show any text on the band, i can see the buttons on my band, the position of the third button is not correct, and there is no text in two of the buttons.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: @HassanA.AI-Rawi there is no concept of TextBox.. in iOS  i thing you want to say UITextField right?

Comment: Please replay so that i can help you.

Comment: No, I'm using Microsoft Band Framework to create tiles on my Microsoft Band. UITextField is a Text Box if you want a text field on your phone, not on the watch.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have created one layout with a horizontal scroll panel. And that panel has pictureFlowPanel, movieFlowPanel, brustButton as its elements.

So when you create pages you will just need to create one page with the above layout. However, in your code I see you are trying to create three pages with layout index 0, 1 and 2. Only layout 0 is valid and layouts 1 and 2 do not exist.

One possible fix is to break apart the layouts into three separate layouts:

```
MSBPageLayout *pictureLayout = [[MSBPageLayout alloc] init];
pictureLayout.root = pictureFlowPanel;
[tile.pageLayouts addObject:pictureLayout]; //Layout 0

MSBPageLayout *movieLayout = [[MSBPageLayout alloc] init];
movieLayout.root = movieFlowPanel;
[tile.pageLayouts addObject:movieLayout]; //Layout 1

MSBPageLayout *burstLayout = [[MSBPageLayout alloc] init];
burstLayout.root = burstFlowPanel;
[tile.pageLayouts addObject:burstLayout]; //Layout 2
```